# android time mode check

Tags: android

How to identify whether Android phone clock is set to hours mode or AM/PM mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try out is24HourFormat function of the DateFormat class. It should return true if the user has selected 24-hour-format, otherwise false. Have a look at the docs too: [DateFormat.is24HourFormat(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat%28android.content.Context%29)